# How to transfer variables from Matlab to Python

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

I would like to transfer some of variables calculated in Matlab (R2022a) to Python environment (3.10).

I have figured out that the SciPy package has function `loadmat()` and I may save vars in mat file and then I should read the file with Python. However, I'm not able to use the function.

```
import scipy
scipy.loadmat('myVars.mat')
```

The interpreter argues that there is no such function as `loadmat()`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You are importing the wrong package, check the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/io.html#:%7E:text=import%20scipy.io%20as%20sio).

```
import scipy.io as sio

mat_file = sio.loadmat('myVars.mat')
```